# Problema com método post/get para atualizar tabela

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando realizar um Update na minha tabela através do javascript para que não tenha que sair da tela toda vez que inativo um campo, minha tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O botão que eu usava em PHP mas ia para outra página:

```
<td class="center">

    <?php echo"<a class='btn btn-danger' href='update_produto.php?ID=$id'>Inativar</a>";?>

</td>
```

Meu botão:

```
<button id='botao-olho' onclick='myFunction()'>Inativar</button>"
```

Aqui o script que vai para o update

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var btn_olho = $("#botao-olho");

btn_olho.on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "update_produto.php",
        type:"html",
        dataType: "GET",
        data: {id: <?php echo $id ?>}
    }).done(function(retorno){

    });

});
```

aqui o update:

```
$id = $_GET['ID'];
$estado = 'Inativo';
$sql = "UPDATE MASTER_COLETORES SET ESTADO = '$estado' WHERE ID = $id";
$stmt = oci_parse($conexao, $sql);
$result = oci_execute($stmt);
```

Clico no botão e não acontece nada :T

Comment: Todos os botões tem o mesmo `id='botao-olho'`? Se sim, está errado, deveria ser `class='botao-olho'`.

Comment: Esse `<?php echo $id ?>` me parece errado tb. O `id` no data do Ajax deveria ser dinâmico de acordo com o botão clicado.

Comment: Troquei para class e não mudou nada...o id vem do mysql que eu utilizo para popular a tabela

Comment: Que função é essa: `onclick='myFunction()'`?

Comment: Eu não entendo de javascript, como eu vi o on click no script, eu coloquei dentro do botão, não precisa?

Comment: Precisa não. Onde tem no HTML o `id` que vc quer enviar?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o botão que funciona com o php

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85968/discussion-between-sam-and-ricardo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não pode usar o mesmo `id` em todos os botões. Um `id` deve ser único na página. Por isso troque o `id` por `class` e retire o `onclick` que não tem função alguma:

```
<button class='botao-olho'>Inativar</button>
```

E adicione um `data-id` para pegar o id que você quer enviar pelo botão clicado, concatenando a variável `$id` do PHP:

```
<?php echo "<button data-id='".$id."' class='botao-olho'> Inativar </button>"; ?>
```

Agora o Ajax você irá usar apenas:

```
$(".botao-olho").on("click", function(){
   var $this = $(this); // salva o elemento numa variável
    $.ajax({
        url: "update_produto.php",
        data: {id: $this.data("id")}, // envia o id
        success: function(){
           $this.closest("tr").remove(); // remove a linha se ocorreu tudo ok
        }
    });
});
```

No PHP requisitado pelo Ajax você coloca o ID em minúsculo no GET:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Nas opções do Ajax você inverteu os valores de `type` e `dataType`, mas nem precisa dessas opções já que por padrão o Ajax envia via GET e você não espera nenhum retorno, apenas enviar o `id`. Também não precisa do `.done`, basta um `success` para remover a linha onde está o botão.

Comment: Funcionou de primeira! Show!

Comment: eu tentei fazer para update de uma tabela, para alterar a quantidade, para mandar o id ok, como eu mando a quantidade no data do javascript? Valeu @Sam

Comment: iSSO, seria em outra tabela para alterar a quantidade, mas o processo é o mesmo

Comment: Ficaria assim: `data: {id: $this.data("id"), quantidade: $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text().trim() },`

Comment: É outra tabela Sam, bem mais simples, e tem um botão alterar nela invez de inativar, como eu pus um data-qtd = $quantidade , ta certo isso?

Comment: pode ser tb, fica mais fácil de pegar com `$this.data("qtd")`

Comment: Cara..não altera, abre um chat..é 3 linhas e acho que resolve :(

Comment: blz... deixa eu ver se abar aqui o chat

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86027/discussion-between-sam-and-ricardo).